# visual studio 'iif function'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am creating a report in visual studio showing 4 items:-

- Invoice Amount
- Paid Amount
- Unpaid Amount
- Of Which Overdue

as shown here:
[image]

what I am trying to due is create a calculation on the fields in dataset to show an amount for my item 'Of which Overdue' when the unpaid amount is over 30 days old.

my dataset is here:
[image]

I have tried to do something like this:

```
=iif((Sum(Fields!DaysOutstanding.Value, "Services")>30, Sum(Fields!BalanceOutstanding.Value, "Services"))
```

But this obviously does not work.

Can anyone point me ion the right diorection?

All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three parameters. You only have two.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
Public Function IIf( _
   ByVal Expression As Boolean, _ 
   ByVal TruePart As Object, _ 
   ByVal FalsePart As Object _ 
) As Object
```

I'm not sure why you're using SUM here. For your case, you'll need to go through your data to do something like this (pseudocode, obviously):

```
 iif(
  If the DaysOutstanding.Value is greater than 30,
  then add balanceoutstanding.value to overdueunpaid.value,
  else add nothing
  )
```

Comment: okay that makes sense, every IIf function needs 3 parts .... but I'm still not sure on how to write that for what I want?

Comment: this is what I have so far .... =(IIf(Sum(Fields!DaysOutstanding.Value, "Services") > 30, ("Sum(Fields!BalanceOutstanding.Value, "Services")", "0"))

Comment: Tnanks for all your help.  I sued the following code based on your prompting ....  =iif((
  Fields!DaysOutstanding.Value) > 30,
 (Fields!BalanceOutstanding.value)  + (Fields!OverdueUnpaid.Value),
  nothing
  )

Answer (score 0):

the following code sorted my problem out

```
=iif((
Fields!DaysOutstanding.Value) > 30,
(Fields!BalanceOutstanding.value)  + (Fields!OverdueUnpaid.Value),
 nothing
 )
```